# How to make a proper authentication with an ASHX Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, handler

I am using ASP.NET's generic handler (ASHX files) to make server-side pages that can return data to mobile apps and so on. Some of this data is ment to be private. I am using JSON & the POST method as of now.

However, anyone with access to a client-side code (for example the code of the Mobile App), would be able to see what keywords he has to send to the "unpredictable" URL in order to make changes or get data.

I've been doing research for hours and couldn't find a proper way to authenticate that the one sending the JSON request is indeed an approved mobile app.

*Example of sending a request to the server with AJAX:*

```
function login() 
{
    var jsonParam = { name: "test", aname: "secret", pass: "1234", type: "login" }
    $.ajax({
        url: "AppDatabase.ashx",
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonParam),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async:false,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.userEmail);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + "\r\n" + "Error: " + errorThrown);
        }    
    });
}
```

*Example of receiving the request on the server side:*

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    string json;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

    if(dict["aname"].ToString() == "secret")
    {
      // The best security I have right now is a "secret keyword" within the request
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean you are sending secret keyword from clientside ??

Comment: @Furqan yes, where else?

Comment: If you want to stop any other 3rd party application to access the URL, then this is NOT possible. Once URL is public it is accessible by anyone, only way to stop is by implementing User Authentication. But still 3rd party can access the resource if they have the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your current way is very dangerous.

You can use another page that needs username & password to authenticate (for ex. using `Session`) and then let client to request your *ashx* file and your *ashx* should check `Session` for authentication.

Comment: Not sure I get this. How can I achieve that? And how can I even assign a Session to the client on a handler?

Comment: Oh. I think I'm getting you. You're saying, attach a Session to whichever sender that logs in, then whenever a request other than login is received, check the validity of the session.

So for one to get another's information, they're gonna have to know both the name and the password. 

I'd still like to hear if anyone has more suggestions on how to make it secure though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought:

Are clients (e.g. mobile app) "yours" or is this meant to be some sort of API (for x clients)?

Either way, maybe worth looking into [JWT](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html)? The idea is that the "payload" (data) is *signed* (e.g. HMAC SHA-256) and has protections against "replays".

This way, you're not just looking to the auth part - re: both ends need to verify the *data* so both can ensure such data came from the "right origin" and is (still) valid.

Hth...

Comment: The mobile apps are mine. I will take a look at JWT, thank you.